# How to do Desktop GUI testing using Cucumber JVM (consistent behavior across devices)?

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm

I have written a Framework on top of Cucumber-JVM which sports configurable and plug-able step implementations. It is integrated with Continuous Integration server Jenkins and runs several thousands of steps in the scenarios/ features and generates html reports & emails on pre-scheduled or on-demand basis for some of the projects. I have written generic plugins which enables configurable step implementations by testers without writing implementation code. I have implemented generic plugins for Web Services (SOAP/ REST), HTTP, FTP/ SFTP, File Generators/ Processors, Database Operations, Web GUI (integrating with Selenium), OS calls, and several other proprietary protocols. I have been pretty successful in rolling out these to teams.

However some of the projects require testing in Desktop GUI for which I do not have generic plugin yet. I have done some research to identify Desktop GUI automation practices and free/ open source tools - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools, 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/web-application-gui-automation-best-practices, [Windows GUI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952666/windows-gui-automation)

In general, Desktop GUI tools are based on image recognition and pointer locations which makes the automation difficult to be consistent across devices (different laptops, desktops etc). Sikuli http://www.sikuli.org/ tool is promising, but this is also not an exception for the inconsistency.

Now questions are :
1. Has anyone automated Desktop GUI with cucumber which gives consistent behavior?
2. Any best practices you could share, point to, with respect to Desktop GUI automation through Cucumber?
3. Any suggestion on the tools to integrate with Cucumber for achieving this?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I have a similar requirement of automating a desktop application. I have done good amount of work using Cucumber-JVM too, a reason for me to get back to it for a desktop application that I am working on currently. Can you please let me know if you have found the right tool and if so, share your evaluation ?

Comment: After some research and feedback from other forums, I am inclined to go in the direction of Sikuli Java APIs for building plugin to my framework to automate for Desktop/Client GUI. However I have not progressed much further yet as the use cases are pretty low compared to other priority items in hand. Please keep posted if you progress.